# cor.test R Error incompatible dimensions

Tags: r, correlation

I would like to generate correlations between years in a dataset in R, however I keep getting the following error:

```
cor.test(y2013$CA,y2011$CA, method="spearman", use="complete")
```

Error in cor(x, y, use = use, method = method) : incompatible dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(x, y) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

y2013 and y2011 are not the same in length, however I thought by using the command "complete" this would eliminate this problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you meant `cor.test` not `corr.test`. You can't input vectors of different lengths as arguments to `cor.test`. You have to fill in the missing values with `NA`. So:

```
cor(1:3,1:4,use='complete.obs') # Fails
cor(c(1:3,NA),1:4,use='complete.obs') # Works
```

You can learn more about how the `use='complete.obs'` argument works at `?cor`.